# Power series approximation for intractable function? (using Solve)

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

Note: I am using `2*x+cos(x)` as an example below. I'm asking this question for any function where `Solve[]` doesn't yield a closed form result. My specific interest at the moment is getting Mathematica to spit out the (well known) power series expansion solution of Kepler's Equation of the Center, just as a test.

The function `2*x+cos(x)` is monotonic increasing (derivative is `2-sin(x)`), and thus invertible. There's no simple form for the inverse:

```
 
Solve[2*x+Cos[x] == y, x]                                                  

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

Question: can I get a power series approximation to the solution? Either using Mathematica builtin functions or some sort of voodoo?

Comment: For $y\ll1$ you can expand $\cos(x)=1-x^2/2$ and solve the quadratic equation $1+(2x-y)-x^2/2=0$. For $y\rightarrow\infty$ the solution is $2x\approx y$. Power series can be likewise used to improve it.

Comment: @yarchik Thanks! Actually, I was asking for functions in general and just using that as an example. I did consider expanding `Cos[x]` as a power series and solving the polynomial, but that doesn't really give me a power series.

Comment: Well, formally the solution to your problem is easy: make a series expansion of the l.h.s. and invert the series ('InverseSeries'). However, this will not be a good approach in your case. Much better is to start from a good guess (to guarantee the convergence) and apply (analytically) the Newton's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries.html) or better yet use [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)

```
Clear[f, g, gs]

f[x_] = 2 x + Cos[x];

g[x_] := InverseFunction[f][x]

gs[x_] = InverseSeries[Series[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]] // Normal;

Prepend[Table[
   {x, f[g[x]], g[f[x]], f[gs[x]], gs[f[x]]},
   {x, -2., 2., 0.25}],
  Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
   {"x", "f[g[x]]", "g[f[x]]", "f[gs[x]]", 
    "gs[f[x]]"}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

As with any series expansion,`InverseSeries` only works well close to the expansion point.

Comment: Didn't know about `InverseSeries`, thanks! I'm using the results externally, so `InverseFunction` wouldn't work.

Comment: @barrycarter - Thanks for the accept. I recommend that you always look at the `See Also` section of the documentation page (for `Series` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

The new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) can be used to find the perturbation expansions. For example, here's the solution for `x` when `y` is expanded about `1` (as in Bob's answer):

```
AsymptoticSolve[2 x + Cos[x] == y, {x, 0}, {y, 1, 4}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2 (-1 + y) + 1/16 (-1 + y)^2 + 1/64 (-1 + y)^3 + (11 (-1 + y)^4)/
>       3072}}

Alternatively, we can solve the equation for when `y` is 0:

```
root = x /. First @ Solve[2 x + Cos[x] == 0, x, Reals];
root //InputForm
```

> Root[{Cos[#1] + 2*#1 & , -0.45018361129487357303766415558147048184`20.60205991050527}]

Since the above root object is hard to process, I'll introduce a symbol `γ` that is equal to the root but displays better:

```
NumericQ[γ] = True;
N[γ, _] := root;
```

Then, using [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) again:

```
AsymptoticSolve[2 x + Cos[x] == y, {x, γ}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

> {{x -> γ + y/(2 - Sin[γ]) - (y^2 Cos[γ])/(
>       2 (-2 + Sin[γ])^3) + (
>       y^3 (-3 Cos[γ]^2 + 2 Sin[γ] - Sin[γ]^2))/(
>       6 (-2 + Sin[γ])^5)}}